# raspi A constantly unresponsive

Tags: raspbian

After a few minutes even mid-process, it becomes unresponsive with solid ACT and PWR leds on. New SSH connections time out, mid-process operations either fail due to broken pipe or host down. It seems to only work for a few minutes at a time. I was able to configure it (a little at a time before it freezes), change the password (which persisted) and have attempted to update the firmware, which would freeze at different phases throughout the processI have flashed the latest Raspian (version dated 5-5-2015), am using a class 10 scandisk microsd card. I have tried using several different usb power adapters (blackberry charger, a generic multi prong adapter and an apple wall charger with a mophie usb cable) all of which had the necessary specs as dictated by the raspberrypi.org page. I have also tried several fresh os installs. This is the futhest I have gotten in that process before became unresponsive:

```
 *** Backing up modules 3.18.11+
#############################################################
WARNING: This update bumps to rpi-4.0.y linux tree
Be aware there could be compatibility issues with some drivers
Discussion here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=113753
##############################################################
Would you like to proceed? (y/N)
 *** Downloading specific firmware revision (this will take a few minutes)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   168    0   168    0     0    637      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   861
100 46.8M  100 46.8M    0     0   574k      0  0:01:23  0:01:23 --:--:--  447k
 *** Updating firmware
Write failed: Host is down
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested the actual voltage at the board, just because a charger says it supplies the required voltage/current does not mean that it does.

Comment: @SteveRobillard How would I go about that without a meter? Also, it seems to works for a random amount of minutes before going down, even without activity.

Comment: You need a meter but just because the label says 5 volts does not mean that is what it actually delivers. I would also try a different SD card not just reformatting. What else do you have connected to your Pi. FYI power issues can appear randomly.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I bought a second card earlier today and tried with that one, still nothing. Froze while trying to install pip, except this time all of the leds are still on. I would like to say this happens whenever I write to the card but I have written to it successfully after boot while still maintaining functionality for a short time afterwards.

Comment: If you have a screen attached check the top right corner for a rainblow square of colours.  It only appears when the Pi voltage drops beneath 4.65 volts.

Comment: There are decent voltage meters for about $12-$15. The expense is absolutely worthwhile.

Comment: @joan there is no rainbow square. Also, my BeagleBone Black seems to have similar power requirements and runs fine on the same chargers.

Comment: How are you connected to the Pi? Wired or wireless?

Comment: @joan ethernet over router. But this even happens when it is connected directly to the TV with hdmi and keyboard

Comment: @Verbal_Kint I'm stumped.  I've known wireless dongles which hang when they go into power save mode but I've never had a problem with a wired connection.  I think you are going to have to borrow a meter and check the delivered voltage is around 5V.

Comment: Based on your post, it looks like a network issue vs. an SD issue. If you hook it up to the TV and just boot it up (no ethernet), do nothing but log into the command line terminal, does it still crash after a few minutes? Or is it just after you are doing something that involves writing to the SD card? Does it crash during writing w/ no network activity? Also, please post /var/syslog